# making an etchasketch program having trouble keeping the turtle going on just a press of a button

Tags: python

This program is an etchasketch program that uses turtle and I'm trying to figure out how to keep the turtle going without holding down the keys for the direction of the turtle.

```
from turtle import *
import sys
import keyboard

PIXEL_MOVE = 20

def main():
    running = True
    pen_down = False
    keep_moving = True
    
    print("This is lab 7")
    screen_width = int(sys.argv[1])
    screen_height = int(sys.argv[2])

    #setting the size and color of the backround and turtle
    screensize(screen_width, screen_height)

    tobject = Turtle("turtle")
    tobject.up()

    while running:
        tobject.forward(PIXEL_MOVE)
        
        event = keyboard.read_event()
        if event.event_type == keyboard.KEY_DOWN:
            if event.name == 'q':
                running = False
            elif event.name == "p":
                if pen_down == False:
                    pen_down = True
                    tobject.down()
                else:
                    pen_down == False
                    tobject.up()
            elif event.name == 'w':
                tobject.setheading(90)
            elif event.name == 'a':
                tobject.setheading(180)
            elif event.name == 's':
                tobject.setheading(270)
            elif event.name == 'd':
                tobject.setheading(0)

main()
```

I got it to keep going in the direction if the key is being held down and pressed. But I want it to be able to move with just a keystroke and keep moving in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to store the last pressed key or last moved direction in a variable.

```
lastPressed = None
while running:
    # Code before reading event
    if event.event_type == keyboard.KEY_DOWN:
        lastPressed = event.name
    if lastPressed:
        # Check if "w", "a", "s", "d", etc. and move
```

Hope this helps in some way :)